# Generating php script for calculating points

Tags: php

I need to prepare a script in php please help me creating such

```
$a=50;
$b=40;
$c=80;
$d=20;
$e=60;
$total=$a+$b+$c+$d+$e // i.e 250
$avg=($a+$b+$c+$d+$e)/5; //i.e 50
```

means every elements need to have 50 points

I have created two arrays 
    i)who will recieve
    ii)who will pay
now what i need is to display a message

```
1)$a do not need to give or recieve any point
/* payer */
    a)$b need to give 10 points to $e.
    b)$d need to give 30 points to $c.
/* payer */

/* reciever*/
    a)$c will recieve 30 points from $d.
    b)$e will recieve 10 points from $b.

/* reciever*/
```

now i am stucked how to create logic to display such message. 
 please help by suggesting me or giving me some idea to do this
 currently there are 5 elements it may be more than that(can be dynamic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find following, it may help you:

```
<?php 
/*
$a=50;
$b=40;
$c=80;
$d=20;
$e=80;
$total=$a+$b+$c+$d+$e; // i.e 250
$avg=($a+$b+$c+$d+$e)/5; //i.e 50
*/

// My code start from here
$payer_array = array();
$receiver_array = array();
$element_array = array('a'=>50, 'b'=>40, 'c'=>80, 'd'=>20, 'e'=>50);
$total_element=count($element_array);
$total = array_sum($element_array);
$avg = $total/$total_element;


foreach($element_array as $name=>$payer_value) {
    if($payer_value>=$avg) {
        $payer_array[$name] = ($payer_value-$avg);
    }
    else {
        $receiver_array[$name] = ($avg-$payer_value);
    }
}

foreach ($payer_array as $name=>$payer_value) {
    if ($payer_value==0) {
        echo "$name do not need to give or receive any point</br>";
    }
    else {
        // exact match 
        if (in_array($payer_value, $receiver_array)) {
            $match_reciever_name =  array_search($payer_value, $receiver_array);
            echo "$name need to give $payer_value points to $match_reciever_name<br/>";
            unset($receiver_array[$match_reciever_name]);
        }
        // partial match 
        else {
            foreach($receiver_array as $reciever_name=>$reciever_value) {
                if($payer_value>0) {
                    if($reciever_value > $payer_value) {
                        $recieverd_value =  $payer_value;
                        echo "$name need to give $recieverd_value points to $reciever_name<br/>";
                        $receiver_array[$reciever_name] = $reciever_value-$recieverd_value;
                        $payer_value = 0;
                        if($receiver_array[$reciever_name]==0) {
                            unset($receiver_array[$reciever_name]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        $recieverd_value =  $reciever_value;
                        echo "$name need to give $recieverd_value points to $reciever_name<br/>";
                        unset($receiver_array[$reciever_name]);
                        $payer_value = $payer_value-$reciever_value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```